# How to load test resources

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-cli

I'm testing Angular 9. I read all the documentation and created a simple website that needs to parse some text file the user can drag and drop. I have a service for the parsing part and now I'm trying to create some test. I come from Java and what I'd normally do is to add some test resource/file to cover all the edge cases and write unit tests that load and parse those tests resources. I tried to read those files using the `fs` Node module but when I run `ng test` I get *Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'*.

I basically just want to be able to load test resources/files into a `File` instance to pass it to the service I'm testing, is there a proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

just create a .ts file in your project and add content in it like following:

data.ts

```
export const TestData = {
// you can add your data here
}
```

and import the **data.ts** file in your .spec.ts file as below

```
import {TestData} from './data.ts';
```

Now you can use **TestData** as a variable and send it to any service

You can store string data in .ts file and use following function to convert string into binary file.

```
readBinaryFile(base64: string, type: string, name: string) {
    const data = atob(base64);
    const array = new Uint8Array(data.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        array[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const file = new File([array], name, { type });
    return file;
}
```

Comment: I get it, that's what I have. I'm talking about test assets/resources. How do I load a test file, say a test .csv that I need to pass to a service in the spec.ts?

Comment: Please check updates and let me know if it works for you

Comment: Ok, that helps thanks. What if I need a binary file in my tests.. say a PDF file to test a PDF parsing service?

Comment: If this helped you, Please mark it as answer so others can follow it, For PDF parsing there is no in built functionality in angular, You can use external package for the same: find this url with the example https://onthecode.co.uk/parse-pdf-documents-in-angular-with-pdfjs/

Comment: I know about PDFjs... the PDF type was just an example. I was asking how do I load binary test files/assets in my unit tests, which is kind of what I asked in the question. I could use your solution in some cases but I'd like to know if there is more general way to load test data from files (binary and not binary) in unit tests.